# wrong image sizing with scrollbar under firefox

Tags: image, firefox, scaling

Here's the problem:

For Chrome, Opera, Safari everthing is fine:

[chrome, opera, edge thumb-bar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3rvwg.jpg)

But firefox has a problem:

[firefox thumbbar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y64jb.jpg)

The problem is caused by the x-scrollbar which pushes each ".thumbs" and 
their children up. The children keep their aspect/ratio thanks to the 
combination of height: 100% and object-fit contain, not leaving any gap between them, EXCEPT under firefox. It seems that ".thumbs" doesn't want to wrap correctly around its child image. The height gets adapted, but not the width. I've tried already different combinations of flex: - shorthands, but nothing helped.

```css
    .scroll_wrapper {
      position: relative;
      overflow: hidden;
      height: 100px;
    }

    .thumbs_container {
      position: absolute;
      display: -webkit-box;
      display: -moz-box;
      display: -ms-flex;
      display: -webkit-flex;
      display: flex;
      flex-flow: row nowrap;
      overflow-x: scroll;
      height: 100%;
      width: 100%;
    }

    .thumbs {
      display: -webkit-box;
      display: -moz-box;
      display: -ms-flex;
      display: -webkit-flex;
      display: flex;
      flex-flow: column nowrap;
      height: 100%;
    }

    .thumbs_imgs {
      height: 100%;
      object-fit: contain;
    }
```

```html
    <div class="scroll_wrapper">
      <div class="thumbs_container">
        <div class="thumbs">
          <img src="http://placeimg.com/170/110/any" alt="1" class="thumbs_imgs"/>
        </div>
        <div class="thumbs">
          <img src="http://placeimg.com/170/115/any" alt="2" class="thumbs_imgs"/>
        </div>
        <div class="thumbs">
          <img src="http://placeimg.com/170/120/any" alt="3" class="thumbs_imgs"/>
        </div>
        <div class="thumbs">
          <img src="http://placeimg.com/170/125/any" alt="4" class="thumbs_imgs"/>
        </div>
        <div class="thumbs">
          <img src="http://placeimg.com/170/130/any" alt="5" class="thumbs_imgs"/>
        </div>
        <div class="thumbs">
          <img src="http://placeimg.com/170/135/any" alt="6" class="thumbs_imgs"/>
        </div>
        <div class="thumbs">
          <img src="http://placeimg.com/170/135/any" alt="7" class="thumbs_imgs"/>
        </div>
        <div class="thumbs">
          <img src="http://placeimg.com/170/140/any" alt="8" class="thumbs_imgs"/>
        </div>
        <div class="thumbs">
          <img src="http://placeimg.com/170/145/any" alt="9" class="thumbs_imgs"/>
        </div>
        <div class="thumbs">
          <img src="http://placeimg.com/170/150/any" alt="10" class="thumbs_imgs"/>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: [You do not need to mark questions as "SOLVED" via editing the title](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/116105/295637), or [posting updates/thanks in posts.](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/109959/295637). Simply add your own answer, and mark as accepted. Anything additional can be perceived as noise for future visitors. See: [Can I answer my own question?](//stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution with a js-workaround:

- firefox bug:

  js loops through the width of each img and gives each parent ".thumbs" the corresponding width.
- x-scrollbar-hide:

  -js gets the height of the outer `.scroll-wrapper`
  -js gets the difference of `.thumbs_container` - `.thumbs` to get the width of the scrollbar (exactly for each browser, because different)
  -js gives the heights of `.scroll-wrapper` + scrollbar-height to `.thumbs_container`

```js
window.onload = function() {
      scrollbarHide()
    }

    function scrollbarHide(){
      var modalThumbsScrollWrapper = document.getElementsByClassName("scroll_wrapper")[0];
      var modalThumbsScrollWrapperHeight = modalThumbsScrollWrapper.offsetHeight;
      var modalThumbsContainer = document.getElementsByClassName('thumbs_container')[0];
      var modalThumbsContainerHeight = modalThumbsContainer.offsetHeight;
      var modalThumbs = document.getElementsByClassName('thumbs')[0];
      var modalThumbsHeight = modalThumbs.offsetHeight;
      var scrollbarHeight = modalThumbsContainerHeight - modalThumbsHeight;
      var newModalThumbsContainerHeight = modalThumbsScrollWrapperHeight + scrollbarHeight;

      modalThumbsContainer.style.height = newModalThumbsContainerHeight + "px";
      modalThumbsWidthCorrectionFF() 
    }

    function modalThumbsWidthCorrectionFF(){  
        var modalThumbs = document.getElementsByClassName('thumbs');
        var modalThumbsLength = modalThumbs.length;
        var modalThumbsImgs = document.getElementsByClassName('thumbs_imgs');
        for (var i = 0; i < modalThumbsLength; i++) {
          modalThumbs[i].style.width = modalThumbsImgs[i].offsetWidth + "px";
        }
    }
```

```css
.scroll_wrapper {
          position: relative;
          overflow: hidden;
          height: 100px;
        }

        .thumbs_container {
          position: absolute;
          display: -webkit-box;
          display: -moz-box;
          display: -ms-flex;
          display: -webkit-flex;
          display: flex;
          flex-flow: row nowrap;
          overflow-x: scroll;
          height: 100%;
          width: 100%;
        }

        .thumbs {
          display: -webkit-box;
          display: -moz-box;
          display: -ms-flex;
          display: -webkit-flex;
          display: flex;
          flex-flow: column nowrap;
          height: 100%;
        }

        .thumbs_imgs {
          height: 100%;
          object-fit: contain;
        }
```

```html
<div class="scroll_wrapper">
          <div class="thumbs_container">
            <div class="thumbs">
              <img src="http://placeimg.com/170/110/any" alt="1" class="thumbs_imgs"/>
            </div>
            <div class="thumbs">
              <img src="http://placeimg.com/170/115/any" alt="2" class="thumbs_imgs"/>
            </div>
            <div class="thumbs">
              <img src="http://placeimg.com/170/120/any" alt="3" class="thumbs_imgs"/>
            </div>
            <div class="thumbs">
              <img src="http://placeimg.com/170/125/any" alt="4" class="thumbs_imgs"/>
            </div>
            <div class="thumbs">
              <img src="http://placeimg.com/170/130/any" alt="5" class="thumbs_imgs"/>
            </div>
            <div class="thumbs">
              <img src="http://placeimg.com/170/135/any" alt="6" class="thumbs_imgs"/>
            </div>
            <div class="thumbs">
              <img src="http://placeimg.com/170/135/any" alt="7" class="thumbs_imgs"/>
            </div>
            <div class="thumbs">
              <img src="http://placeimg.com/170/140/any" alt="8" class="thumbs_imgs"/>
            </div>
            <div class="thumbs">
              <img src="http://placeimg.com/170/145/any" alt="9" class="thumbs_imgs"/>
            </div>
            <div class="thumbs">
              <img src="http://placeimg.com/170/150/any" alt="10" class="thumbs_imgs"/>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: Here at stackoverflow: We care about 2 things mainly: Good questions, and good answers. We *encourage* users to post answers, so that future readers that happen upon this post can see a question and answer(s) to the question. Adding *thanks* or other things not necessary to ask or answer the question is simply noise, and is discouraged by the majority of users on the site.